# How to constantly validate a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java application that has a form with 4 text fields and a button. I was wondering if there is a way for the program to be constantly checking the fields using `.isEmpty()` to see if there has been an input yet, and once there is an input in all fields, the button will become available to click?

Comment: You can implement a `DocumentListener` and check if your textfields are empty.

Comment: What you're sort of suggesting is using a polling approach. You want an event-driven approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a DocumentListener.

```
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                if(field.getText().isEmpty()){
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                if(field.getText().isEmpty()){
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                if(field.getText().isEmpty()){
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Since `String`s are objects use `String::equals` not `==`. Or even better use `String::isEmpty`.

Comment: @Flown I was about to say the same

Comment: Derp, haven't had my coffee yet. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Is there any way to unify these update methods to better stay DRY?

Comment: DocumentListener is an interface, so all these methods must be overridden.  I'm not exactly sure what you mean @AustinSchäfer